accurate calculation for pitchfork indicator
I'm working on creating a manual pitchfork drawing indicator in Pine Script (version 5). The issue I'm facing is that the pitchfork drawn by my indicator is not as accurate as the one drawn using the TradingView drawing tool. The main problem seems to be related to the fact that we can't use float values for bar indices, which is causing the inaccuracy.
I've written a script to draw a pitchfork based on three points (A, B, and C) provided by the user. The script calculates the midpoint of the line segment BC and then draws lines from point A through the midpoint and extends them by 500 bars. However, the lines drawn by my indicator (black) are not aligning perfectly with the lines drawn using the TradingView drawing tool (purple), as shown in the attached image.
I tried calculating the midpoint and extending the lines using integer bar indices. Here's the relevant part of my code:
//@version=5
indicator("Centroid Fork", overlay=true)

// Inputs for Points A, B, C
a = input.price(0, 'A', group='ABC', inline='1', confirm=true)
aBarTime = input.time(0, "", group='ABC', inline='1', confirm=true)
b = input.price(0, 'B', group='ABC', inline='2', confirm=true)
bBarTime = input.time(0, "", group='ABC', inline='2', confirm=true)
c = input.price(0, 'C', group='ABC', inline='3', confirm=true)
cBarTime = input.time(0, "", group='ABC', inline='3', confirm=true)

// Converting time inputs to bar indices
aBarIndex = ta.valuewhen(time == aBarTime, bar_index, 0)
bBarIndex = ta.valuewhen(time == bBarTime, bar_index, 0)
cBarIndex = ta.valuewhen(time == cBarTime, bar_index, 0)

// Calculate midpoint of BC
midpointPrice = (b + c) / 2
midpointBarIndex = math.round((bBarIndex + cBarIndex) / 2)

// Calculate angle from A to midpoint of BC
yDiff = midpointPrice - a
xDiff = midpointBarIndex - aBarIndex
angle = math.atan(yDiff / xDiff)

// Function to extend a line
length = 500 // Extend lines by 500 bars
extend_line(x1, y1, angle, color, width) =>
    x2 = math.round(x1 + length * math.cos(angle))
    y2 = y1 + length * math.sin(angle)
    line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2, color=color, width=width)

// Line settings inputs
lineColor = input.color(color.black, "Line Color", group="Line Settings")
lineWidth = input.int(1, "", minval=1, title="Line Width", group="Line Settings", inline="Line Width", display=display.data_window)

// Draw line from A to midpoint of BC extending 500 bars
extend_line(aBarIndex, a, angle, lineColor, lineWidth)
extend_line(bBarIndex, b, angle, lineColor, lineWidth)
extend_line(cBarIndex, c, angle, lineColor, lineWidth)


I expected the lines drawn by the indicator to match exactly with the lines drawn using the TradingView drawing tool. However, they do not align perfectly, especially on the finer scales.
enter image description here
